# How can we print different types of data types in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, types, printing

I want to print values of all the types like char, long... so on and also nsdate, nsdictionary, frame ....I want to now to print values of each type variables.

Comment: Print them exactly the same way you do in C. For Objective-C types either use NSLog to print them and represent them with %@ or call description and UTF8String and print that using %s with printf and hte like or any other way you would print a string. So, given some NSDate someDate, print with printf like: printf("Some date: %s\n", [[someDate description] UTF8String]);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primitive types such as int, float, double, etc can be printed in the same fashion they are printed in C, using `printf`, `fprintf`, etc.  If you need to print the data of a class you can often use `NSObject`'s method `(NSString *)description` to get a `NSString` representing the data of the object.  Here is an example...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World!"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Hello There!"];

    char *c_string = "Familiar ol' c string!";
    int number = 3;

    printf("C String: %s\n",c_string);
    printf("Int number: %u\n", number);
    //In 10.5+ do not use [NSString cString] as it has been deprecated
    printf("NSString: %s\n", [string UTF8String]);
    printf("NSDate: %s\n", [date.description UTF8String]);
    printf("NSArray: %s\n", [array.description UTF8String]);

    //If you are using this information for debugging, it's often useful to pass the object to NSLOG()

    NSLog(@"NSArray *array = \n%@", array);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I thought it would helpful to see the output when the example is ran...

```
C String: Familiar ol' c string!
Int number: 3
NSString: Hello World!
NSDate: 2010-03-12 01:52:31 -0600
NSArray: (
    "Hello There!"
)
2010-03-12 01:52:31.385 printfTest[2828:a0f] NSArray *array = 
(
    "Hello There!"
)
```

Comment: You can initialize constant NSStrings, just do like NSString* string = @"Some string". stringWithFormat: is an expensive way to initialize since it has to parse the format string, not to mention the unnecessary method invocation. Also, number is a signed integer and %u is for unsigned integers.

Comment: Being new to Objective C... what's the meaning of those "%u"s and "%s" you put before printing integers and strings, respectively? I noticed that they are not printed without, but what does it stand for, anyway?

Comment: arik-so: The %u and %s are called escape sequences.  They aren't technically a part of Objective-C, but rather the printf function.  http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1048379655&id=1043284385

Comment: %u and %s are called tokens, which are used to display different datatypes - %s = string, %d = integer, %0 = octal, %x = hexdecimal, %ld = longint, %lld longlongint and so on.