# How can we print different types of data with one function

Tags: objective-c, macros

It's inspired by:

[How can we print different types of data types in objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430706/how-can-we-print-different-types-of-data-types-in-objective-c)

However, I want an NSLog type of function where if I do

This is my current macro

```
#define ELog( s, ... ) NSLog( @"<%p %@:(%d)> %@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] )
#define DLog( s, ... ) ;;
//#define CLog( s, ... ) ;
#define CLog( s, ... ) NSLog( @"<%p %@:(%d)> %@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] )
#define CM( s, ... );// NSLog( @"<%p %@:(%d)> %@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] )

#define PO1(x) ELog(@#x ": %@", x)
#define PD(x) ELog(@#x ": %f", x)
#define PI(x) ELog(@#x ": %d", x)
```

I want something like this but if I do

PO(somevariable), it'll produce the log I want irrelevant of whether it's an NSObject or double or float or integer.

I think I've seen there somewhere. I searched and couldn't find it.